# Matrix logarithm of unitary matrix from eigendecomposition of Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix and let $A = UDU^*$ be its eigendecomposition. Then what can we say about the Hermitian matrix $B$ where $U = \exp(iB)$? Can we relate it to $A$ in some manner other than the one above mentioned?

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of relationship you're expecting/looking for? Is there a particular motivation for this question?

Comment: Hi Ben, this question forms a part of a larger question that I've asked previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303134/matrix-logarithm-of-unitary-matrix-from-polar-decomposition-of-product-of-positi). There a similar question is asked for SVD instead of eigendecomposition, but I think if there is answer for eigendecompsition, SVD can be answered as well.